# IconFiles in info.plist

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios4

If i want to use several icon in my app should i enter all of them into IconFiles in info.plist?if yes should i delete iconFile from info.plist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use both, especially if your app runs on older versions of iOS, like 3.1.  IconFiles is only for specifying different sizes for the application icon; iOS will choose the most appropriate size depending on the screen resolution.  Specify your 57x57 icon in iconFile, as well as in iconFiles.